# Options For Deleting A Folder, Which Won't Seem to Delete?

Tags: windows-7, file-management, recycle-bin

I'm trying to delete a folder unsuccessfully. When I try to delete it or move it to the Recycle Bin, the following message appears:

[image]

As far as I can tell, it is not open in another program or window.

What options do I have for deletion of this folder ?

Comment: Try to delete it in safe mode? Perhaps some service in the background locked that folder.

Comment: You might have a program in that folder open,check with task manager.

Comment: @Mihai I deleted the contents of the folder.

Comment: Please don't edit your solutions into your question.  Post it as an actual answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I delete a 'locked' file?](http://superuser.com/questions/13291/how-do-i-delete-a-locked-file). Also see [Easy way to find out which process is locking a file or folder in Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/117902/easy-way-to-find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows?lq=1)

Comment: @techie007 Ok fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your options are:

a) reboot your server or machine (maybe even in safe modus) or

b) download one of the countless unlocker tools e.g http://download.cnet.com/Unlocker/3000-2248_4-10493998.html

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241178/command-line-tool-for-finding-out-who-is-locking-a-file

Comment: I have Iobit Unlocker installed, I'll try that now.

Comment: see my edit above

Comment: so... kill TASK chrome :) (taskmanager) then delete directory "london"

Comment: Yes I simply closed Chrome, and that allowed me to delete the folder. I've never come across that before. Thankyou for your help however :)

Comment: I accepted yours as the correct answer as it was Unlocker that identified the problem (even though I didn't have to use it).

Answer (score 0):

I already had Unlocker installed on my PC, as was recommended by edelwater which showed that the folder was "locked" by Chrome as follows:

[image]

It was therefore simply a case of closing the Chrome web browser, which therefore allowed me to delete the folder.

(I did not have to use the functionality of Unlocker to do so. However Unlocker provided the details of why the folder was "locked" in the first place).