# Cannot convert USB drive format via command prompt Windows 10

Tags: command-line, usb

Trying to convert USB drive from FAT32 to NTFS

Command prompt:

```
CONVERT f: /FS:NTFS
```

(where f is the relevant USB drive)

Appears to run through command, but doesn't finish, gives this message:

> Convert cannot run because the volume is in use by another process. Convert may run if this volume is dismounted first. ALL OPENED HANDLES TO THIS VOLUME WOULD THEN BE INVALID. Would you like to force a dismount on this volume? (Y/N)

However it is not in use by any other process.

Entering `Y` to force a dismount does not work

Any suggestions?

Comment: See if you can find the process that is using the USB.. You could use the method by user @Svish here: https://superuser.com/questions/117902/find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows/6614

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, the prompt always means the files are being used on the volume that you are trying to convert. 
You could try to convert format in Safe Mode to check.
Or you can use unlocker program to see what processes have open handles to any files on a drive.
http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/
Also you could right click f drive in File Explorer and choose the format option to check if it works fine.
[image]

Please note: back up important data first.

Comment: Ended up formatting in file explorer. Was trying to avoid that, because didn't want to lose data (the command prompt should have converted without losing data), but it wouldn't work any other way

Answer (score 0):

It definitely sounds like another program has control of the drive, like an anti-virus, spyware, backup, etc.  You can try booting into safe mode and attempting the conversion.  Or booting off a CD/USB and using [Gnome Partition Editor](https://gparted.org).

You can try to figure out what process is using the drive with Sysinternls ProcMon.