# How to detect which process has a file locked in Windows?

Tags: windows, filesystems, process

Sometimes, while trying to edit a file, the editor says "cannot write to file because is taken by another process".
So, is there a tool which takes an input a file name (with its path) and tells which process has taken it with write-only acces?

If not, what is the thecnical reason that cannot be answered?

I ask this because is so annoying that the message does not inform what is the damn process locking the file and cannot understand why the OS programmer didn't give that obvious vital information.
Thanks!

Comment: We are always glad to help, but this question has been asked *many* times before.

Comment: Unfortunately none of the answers worked

Answer (score 0):

Without installing another software, nor programming a power-shell script, the fastest solution was answered here...

https://superuser.com/a/643312/57737

Comment: While we appreciate your feedback, it isn't really appropriate to post a previous answer as a new one.  It would be better to simply accept the `Possible duplicate` that I proposed.

Comment: Sorry. I referred to the second answer to the question because the accepted answer were more complicated (the script). In fact, maybe I saw that question and answer before (I saw a lot more here and in other websites), and was really frustrating not having the simpler one (which really is not that simple for something so common and obvious). Maybe that's why this issue is so many times asked. We are guilty of losing our patience, for those not patience enough to report which process is locking a file (it's like throwing an argument out of range exception without mentioning the name).

Comment: Actually that answer does not say how to do this for a folder. Any thoughts on this?