# Can't modify Windows hosts file because file is in use

Tags: windows, hosts

I am trying to add an entry to my Windows hosts file and I"m having issues. I have already gotten around the Admin permissions issue by opening Notepad as and administrator and then opening the file via Notepad. However, I'm getting a new warning saying that the file is in use by another program and therefore can't be modified.

How can I get around this and update my file?

NOTE:
The exact wording of the message is:

> The process cannot access the file because its being used by another process.

Not sure if this makes a difference but I do have XAMPP installed, but Apache and Mysql are not running.

EDIT:
I have tried looking for the process which might be locking the hosts file with suggestions here [Find out which process is locking a file or folder in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/117902/find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows) but it doesn't even list my file as being locked!

Comment: See if this question helps : [Find out which process is locking a file or folder in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/117902/find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows)

Comment: @Ix07 I don't know anything about Powershell, how exactly do I use that? I had already seen this article and tried the Resource Moniter, but couldn't find my hosts file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find out which process is locking a file or folder in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/117902/find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows)

Comment: @user1015214 - There are other solutions that don't require PowerShell.  Even the PowerShell solution does not require knowledge of PowerShell, the script was provided, in that particular answer.

Comment: @Ramhound Well, its odd. I tried out the Resource Moniter and put 'hosts' in the search and nothing came up.... When I tried Process Exploerer, all I got was svchost.exe, and sihost.exe.

Comment: It could be locked by an antivirus or other security program (which is done to prevent malware from changing the hosts file).

Comment: @DavidPostill How would I figure out how to stop that? Just by brute force and turning everything off?