# process explorer - identify new files

Tags: windows-explorer, process

Issue I have is is possibly the most bizarre I ever faced...
Excel macro (which copies data from one of the sheets and sends via email) runs correctly if Outlook is not running. If Outlook is running it produces an incorrect result - wrong sheet.
Since this shared file works well on a different machine I suspect some small difference in some file version might be causing this.
I therefore need to identify all new files (of any type) that become active once Outlook is started, so that I have at least a starting point in my search for a culprit.
Thank you!

Comment: See if this solution helps you.  https://superuser.com/questions/117902/find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows

Comment: Thanks for checking and suggesting but unfortunately not applicable... my search continues